# Xcode Not Displaying Correct Size In Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have an iPhone 6 to test my app i have my storyboard set to wCompact hRegular it says at the bottom this is for all iPhones in portrait and on the storyboard i can see all the content without a scrollview. However when i actually build and load the app to the device some of the content is off the screen when in the storyboard it shows otherwise. Does it not mean All iPhones in portrait or am i misunderstanding this feature of Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding somewhat. Compact width regular height is a description of the style / shape / attributes of the screen for iPhones in portrait, not the actual size. They're all tall and skinny, but not all by the same amount or with the same aspect ratio.

Size classes allow you to logically group devices and orientations so you can specify the overall style of interaction that's appropriate, then allow auto layout to exactly configure the views to fit the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard and Select Your Viewcontroller in the right pane select show attribute inspector for the particular viewcontroller..and set Size to iphone 4.7 inch and orientation to portrait..and check your alignment is showing correctly ..check the image for references 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrBSj.png